# How to make text flow around the sidebar?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have the sidebar(Seitenleiste) activated in twenty seventeen:

[image]

I want text to flow around

[image]

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

an answer as general as the question: The Element/DIV "Seitenleiste" in this case would have to have "float: right;" in its CSS and be *inside* the "Text" DIV

(try it with a simple floated image instead of "Seitenleiste" as an example, inside a DIV full of text, then you'll see the effect)

Comment: Ich habe mich auf twenty seventeen bezogen. Da gibt es Tricks, wie es genau hier zu schaffen ist. Bei float right war ich auch schon.